# Converting TFS workspace from "Server" to "Local" fails with error "Not a valid Win32 FileTime"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

**Issue**

I am trying to convert a TFS workspace from "Server" to "Local".  When I change the workspace setting and click OK, a dialog titled "Set Workspace Location" appears. It shows a progress bar with the message "Creating and populating the local version table...".  After a few seconds, another dialog replaces it, with the title "Microsoft Visual Studio" and the following message:

*"Error: Not a valid Win32 File Time"*

After I click OK, the error dialog goes away.  The workspace location has not been changed.

**My Configuration**

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.  My workspace type is "Private" and the File Time setting is "Checkin."

**Question**

What is causing this, and how do I get around it so I can convert my workspace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround that allowed me to proceed:

1. First change the workspace's File Time setting to "Current", and
   click OK.
2. Once the operation completes, change the workspace    Location to "Local" as desired, and click OK.

Afterward, you can change the File Time setting back to "Checkin" if desired.

*Note: If your File Time setting was already set to "Current," this workaround will not help you.*